# how to drop a bomb in character position in a pygame game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a pygame game where a character is currently moving around on a screen and can buy items from a shop. I want the character to be able to drop the bombs that he buys from the shop in the location of the player (I need to fix this). I'm attaching my whole code along with some screen shots. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
 import pygame

pygame.font.init()

width = 900
height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([width, height])

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1.png'), pygame.image.load('R2.png'), pygame.image.load('R3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R4.png'), pygame.image.load('R5.png'), pygame.image.load('R6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('R7.png'), pygame.image.load('R8.png'), pygame.image.load('R9.png')]

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1.png'), pygame.image.load('L2.png'), pygame.image.load('L3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L4.png'), pygame.image.load('L5.png'), pygame.image.load('L6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('L7.png'), pygame.image.load('L8.png'), pygame.image.load('L9.png')]

char = pygame.image.load('standing.png')
bomb_pic = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('bomb.png'), (20,20))
# char_rect = char.get_rect()

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = False
down = False
up = False
walkCount = 0
shop = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("shop.png"), (60, 60))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

bag = {'bomb': 0}
print(bag["bomb"])
class Button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):

        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 20)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (
                self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))


def shop_run():
    shop_bomb = Button((0, 200, 0), 820, 150, 60, 20, text="Bomb_q")
    bright_green = (0, 255, 0)
    green = (0, 200, 0)
    shop_bomb.draw(screen)


def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    screen.fill([166, 166, 166])

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (800, 0, 100, 600))
    if x + char.get_width() < 60 and y + char.get_height() < 60:
        shop_run()

    screen.blit(shop, (0, 0))


    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0

    if left:
        screen.blit(walkLeft[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1

    elif right:
        screen.blit(walkRight[walkCount // 3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1

    elif down:
        screen.blit(char, (x, y))
        walkcount = 0

    elif up:
        screen.blit(char, (x, y))
        walkcount = 0

    else:
        screen.blit(char, (x, y))
        walkCount = 0


    buy = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if buy[pygame.K_SPACE] and bag["bomb"] >= 1:
        screen.blit(bomb_pic,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    run = True
    # shopper()
    pygame.display.set_caption("bomb-mania")

    global x
    global y
    global width
    global height
    global vel

    global isJump
    global jumpCount

    global left
    global right
    global down
    global up

    global walkCount

    global bomb_pic
    while run:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False


            if x + char.get_width() < 60 and y + char.get_height() < 60:
                buy = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if buy[pygame.K_q]:
                    bag["bomb"] += 1
                    print(bag["bomb"])


        redrawGameWindow()



        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel - 15:
            x -= vel
            left = True
            right = False
            down = False
            up = False



        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 800 - vel - width:
            x += vel
            left = False
            right = True[![enter image description here][1]][1]
            down = False
            up = False

        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 600 - height:
            y += vel
            left = False
            right = False
            down = True
            up = False

        elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > vel - 15:
            y -= vel
            left = False
            right = False
            down = False
            up = True

        else:
            left = False
            right = False
            down = False
            up = False
            walkCount = 0

        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.flip()


main()
```

[image: the red background is the shop]

[image: the black box is the bomb which is currently appearing at (0, 0)]

Comment: What problem do you have when you tried this? You seem to know how to handle mouse clicks and how to render things on the screen, so what is the concrete problem you've encountered?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman The bomb is not staying on the screen, it disappears as soon as i leave the space bar. Also the bomb is appearing at (0,0). I need it to stay at the location of the player(where he dropped it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a list for the bombs:

```py
bombs = []
```

Add the position of the bomb to the list, when <kbd>space</kbd> is pressed. Use the event loop and the `KEYDOWN` event to spawn bombs, because you want to drap only on bomb when the key is pressed rather than multiple bombs when the key is hold down:

```py
def main():
    global bombs

    while run:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key = pygame.K_SPACE and bag["bomb"] >= 1:
                    bombs.append((x, y))

            # [...]
```

Draw the bombs in `redrawGameWindow` in a loop:

```py
def redrawGameWindow():
    # [...]

    for pos in bombs:
        screen.blit(bomb_pic, pos)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Rabbid, you have always answered my questions accurately. I'm so happy when I see your answers as I know they will work with a simple solution:).  You can just correct the typo in your answer - abbend = append.

Answer (score 2):

You're only drawing the bomb when you press the space bar. You have to draw it continuously. You need to add these three things in your code (not directly after each other as shown here).

```
# Create a list to keep track on the bombs positions (do this **before** 
# the game loop). Could be a global variable if you want.
bomb_positions = [] 


# Add a bomb when you press space. Do this in the event loop and not with 
# 'pygame.key.get_pressed()', because that will add a new bomb every frame if 
# you hold down the spacebar.
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        bomb_positions.append((x, y)) 


# Draw all the bombs at their position. If the list is empty, nothing will 
# be drawn.
for bomb_position in bomb_positions:
    screen.blit(bomb_pic, bomb_position)
```